# Google Geocoding API returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: php, json, curl

Usando la api geocode de google siempre me funciona bien a no ser que la address sea la siguiente "address=same+airport", usando mi codigo obtengo zero_result, pero si accedo al url directamente en el navegador los resultados se muestran, el error ocurre solo con esa address, cualquier otra funciona correctamente

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY&address=same+airport&sensor=false";


$ch = curl_init();

$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$jsondata = json_decode($data,true);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response);

$newlat  = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;

return $newlat;
```

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($response);`?

Comment: object(stdClass)#1822 (2) { ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(12) "ZERO_RESULTS" }

Comment: Intenta con `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?address=same+airport&sensor=false&key=API_KEY`

Comment: en ese caso obtengo con var_dump($response);  "object(stdClass)#1822 (2) { ["predictions"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(15) "INVALID_REQUEST" }"

Comment: Intenta así: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?address=same+airport&key=API_KEY`  o bien `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=same+airport&key=API_KEY`

Comment: en el primer caso resulta "INVALID_REQUEST" y en el segundo "ZERO_RESULTS"

Comment: Prueba así: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/textsearch/json?query=same+airport&key=API_KEY`

Comment: En ese caso resulta "NULL"

Comment: Intenta agregar esto a las opciones cURL: `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>'GET'`  e intenta con tu URL original.

Comment: Se obtiene "ZERO_RESULTS"

Comment: Lo que he podido leer es que esto ocurre por problemas de ambigüedad. Prueba a ponerle el país: `address=same+airport+ELPAISAQUI`

Comment: Ahora si funciona! pero sucede que no tengo esa variable, sino que el pais es un dato que tambien solicito, habra otra manera de hacerlo funcionar si no tengo el pais?

Comment: Como te decía, `ZERO_RESULTS` es un indicatvo de **ambigüedad**. En la doc decían algo sobre probar con `places` pero no sé realmente que URL habría que usar en ese caso. De todos modos, si pides el país lo puedes llevar al contexto antes de hacer la petición y agregarlo ¿no?

Comment: quise decir que el pais es un dato que no tengo, sino que tambien lo solicito  a la api

Comment: le cambie "airport" to "aereopuerto" la misma palabra en otro idioma y funciono!, gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.